# why service account user role(roles/iam.serviceAccountUser) is not required when creating resources with deployment manager template?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I created a custom role from the deployment manager editor role, and I used this role with service account which gives this service account access to create resources using deployment manager in GCP but it doesn't require to add "service account user(roles/iam.serviceAccountUser)" role to this service account, but when I created role to create custom images using packer and used this role with another service account, "service account user" role is required, please let me know why "service account user" is not required when I'm using deployment manager to create resources?

Comment: Please explain "but when I created role to create custom images using packer and used this role with another service account" part. Do you use two different service accounts - one for Deployment Manager and second for Packer ?

Comment: yes, there are two different service accounts, one for the packer and one for deployment manager but the packer requires a "service account user" role but the other service account for deployment manager do not require a service account user role.

Answer (score 2):

> why "service account user" is not required when I'm using deployment
> manager to create resources?

Deployment Manager uses the credentials of the Google APIs service account for permissions to access resources. That identity has the permissions of the role `Editor` which includes the permission `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs`.

The service account name is: `[PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com`

To list the roles modify and use this command:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <PROEJCT_ID>  \
--flatten="bindings[].members" \
--format="table(bindings.role)" \
--filter="bindings.members:<SERVICE_ACCOUNT>"
```

Comment: but I manually removed this "iam.serviceAccounts.actAs." from the  deployment manager editor role, it still works fine, I'm asking why it worked?

Comment: @hritz220 The answer depends on what resources Deployment Manager is creating. To create a Compute Engine VM that has an attached service account requires actAs.

Comment: I manually removed this "iam.serviceAccounts.actAs." from the deployment manager editor role, and created a compute engine VM, it is working without any issue, why it worked that is my question. ?

Comment: @hritz220 1) If the VM that you created does not have a service account attached, then you do not need the ActAs role. 2) How did you remove a permission from a predefined role - that is not possible.

Comment: "If the VM that you created does not have a service account attached, then you do not need the ActAs" that makes sense to me I'll verify it. "I created a custom role from the deployment manager editor role" mentioned in the first line of my question, did not removed permissions from predefined role.